# Recompiling php troubles

Tags: php, unix, compilation

so I know there are somewhat similar questions on here, but I haven't been able to get a helpful answer (not that they're not helpful, just not for my specific question) on another thread.

Also, I'm not quite sure this isn't a SF question, but here goes:

I recently was working on a VPS that had php sans curl. I've tried working around it, but I need to use some curl functions to poll some social networking sites, and I've come to the conclusion I just need to re-compile with curl.

So, I made sure curl was ready for php to grab it, downloaded the latest source, got my current php config from phpinfo, and tried to configure & make. That seemed to go OK, but a make install ended up with 500 errors on all php scripts.

So, I checked my logs, and I'm not seeing any errors except some simple favicon.ico not found and 500.shtml not found warnings. I did see some errors having to do with magicquotes not being supported, so, I figured php wasn't compiled right. I ran configure again, but without the --with-magicquotes flag, and ran make & make test.

Make test failed, I have no clue what to do to try to make it work, and so at this point I'm lost, with a server that won't run php.

Here's my config:

```
./configure --disable-pdo --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-ftp --enable-libxml --enable-sockets --prefix=/usr --with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/ --with-imap-ssl=/usr --with-kerberos --with-libdir=lib64 --with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/ --with-mysql=/usr --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --with-pic --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr --with-curl=/usr/local/lib/
```

Here's the make test message:

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   45
Exts tested     :   33
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 11035              7774
Tests skipped   : 3261 ( 29.6%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :   18 (  0.2%) (  0.2%)
Expected fail   :    8 (  0.1%) (  0.1%)
Tests passed    : 7748 ( 70.2%) ( 99.7%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :  329 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
function with many parameters [tests/func/010.phpt]
Test DateTime::modify() function : usage variation - Passing unexpected values to first argument $modify. [ext/date/tests/DateTime_modify_variation1.phpt]
Bug #50392 date_create_from_format enforces 6 digits for 'u' format character [ext/date/tests/bug50392.phpt]
Test date_modify() function : usage variation - Passing unexpected values to second argument $format. [ext/date/tests/date_modify_variation2.phpt]
mysql connect [ext/mysql/tests/001.phpt]
mysql_connect() [ext/mysql/tests/mysql_connect.phpt]
mysql_[p]connect() - max_links/max_persistent [ext/mysql/tests/mysql_max_links.phpt]
SPL: DirectoryIterator test getGroup [ext/spl/tests/DirectoryIterator_getGroup_basic.phpt]
SPL: Spl Directory Iterator test getOwner [ext/spl/tests/DirectoryIterator_getOwner_basic.phpt]
SQLite3::open error test [ext/sqlite3/tests/sqlite3_15_open_error.phpt]
realpath_cache_size() and realpath_cache_get() [ext/standard/tests/file/realpath_cache.phpt]
Test var_dump() function [ext/standard/tests/general_functions/var_dump_64bit.phpt]
Test gethostbyaddr() function : basic functionality [ext/standard/tests/network/gethostbyaddr_basic1.phpt]
getmxrr() test [ext/standard/tests/network/getmxrr.phpt]
Bug #49936 (crash with ftp stream in php_stream_context_get_option()) [ext/standard/tests/streams/bug49936.phpt]
Test Blowfish crypt() with invalid rounds [ext/standard/tests/strings/crypt_blowfish_invalid_rounds.phpt]
htmlentities() / html_entity_decode() #8592 - #9002 table test [ext/standard/tests/strings/htmlentities17.phpt]
xmlwriter_write_attribute_ns with missing param [ext/xmlwriter/tests/xmlwriter_write_attribute_ns_error_001.phpt]
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
output buffering - fatalism [tests/output/ob_011.phpt]
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]
Bug #42718 (unsafe_raw filter not applied when configured as default filter) [ext/filter/tests/bug42718.phpt]
SimpleXML: array casting bug [ext/simplexml/tests/034.phpt]
=====================================================================

You may have found a problem in PHP.
We would like to send this report automatically to the
PHP QA team, to give us a better understanding of how
the test cases are doing. If you don't want to send it
immediately, you can choose "s" to save the report to
a file that you can send us later.
Do you want to send this report now? [Yns]:
```

I've got no clue where to go from here. I'm a php programmer, not a server admin.

Anybody see anything obviously wrong with what I'm doing here?

Thanks,

Jesse

Comment: For what it's worth, I've also tried yum install php, and I get "no package php available" - I've tried adding the centOS dev repo and a 3rd party repo, but neither seemed to have php. Anybody know of a dependable php repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `make install` (assuming that `make` built everything successfully), try restarting Apache completely.  I've had this before where replacing the php module causes Apache to have issues until you restart it and the new module is loaded in again.

Comment: Make doesn't throw any errors, but I've tried restarting apache after the install, and even stopping apache during the entire make install, with no love. I think the problem is that the php make test fails, so my version of php is in trouble. I've tried using the latest 2 versions of php, but both fail.

Comment: Hmm, that's me out of ideas then I'm sorry! All PHP builds I've done have gone OK assuming I've used a previous `configure` string that worked..!